# Proving tail-recursive function (calculating powers of an integer)

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion, proof

Here's a function whose corectness I want to prove (written in OCaml):

```
let rec pow ak a k = if k=0 then ak
else if (k mod 2)=1 then pow (ak*a) (a*a) (k/2)
else pow ak (a*a) (k/2);;
```

Its specification:

```
For integers ak, a>0, k>=0 pow returns ak*(a^k).
```

I know I need to prove 2 things - that the function terminates, and returns the correct result for the assumed input. The problem is I haven't seen many proofs like that and the only thing I know is that I need to use induction. How should I approach such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Prove the base case. Then prove that for `a+1` and `k+1` the statement is true in assumption that it works for `a` and `k`.

Comment: In other words, recursion is exactly the same as proof by induction.

Comment: How to use induction on two variables at once?

Comment: the same way as on one variable, nothing special